# MySql table replication on the same server

Tags: mysql, server, database-replication

I have two MySql tables on the same server ( for example DB1.customer and DB2.customer ). I want to replicate the content of DB1.customer in DB2.customer and at every INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE of DB1.customer I wanto to sync with DB2.customer. Is possible this with replication ? If yes what's the configuration ? Have I to specify two different server-id ? I've read that in this case I have to install two instance of MySql in different directory and then use two different server-id for each installation, is this true ? Is there any other way to achieve what i'm looking for without install another instance of MySql ?
Thanks a lot for your tips.

Comment: please clarify your question.  It sounds like you are asking a very general question on how to set up database replication and what it can and cant do

Comment: use a vie in the second schema create view customer as SELECT * from DB1.customer; so every time the sam data

Comment: I have two prestaShop database on the same machine that could Share The same customer db. So I have to replicate one customer table to the other. I don't know If I can use replicate or use something else like a view . I never made something liKe this....

Comment: just use a trigger??? so when you do something to DB1.customer such as an insert update or delete then the trigger execute on update, on delete, on insert for DB2.customer...not sure where you got into your head to do replication, etc...

Comment: I'm trying to use Trigger but I get a syntax error : CREATE TRIGGER ins_new AFTER INSERT ON customer  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO DB2.customer ( 'id', 'name', 'email','passwd' ) VALUES ( NEW.'id', NEW.'name', NEW.'email', NEW.'passwd' ) END; Where is my fault ? @BK435

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved with triggers ( like @BK435 suggest... ). This is the code I used from DB1 table:

DELIMETER $$
CREATE TRIGGER ins_new AFTER INSERT ON customer FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO DB2.customer ( 'id', 'name', 'email','passwd' ) 
VALUES ( NEW.'id', NEW.'name', NEW.'email', NEW.'passwd' ) 
END;
$$

Is important to change delimeter if ';' is set as default delimeter.